# How to find a Future Date in Java(say two months from today) in 24 February 2019 format

Tags: java, date-formatting, localdate, date

Below is the approach I am going with :

```
Date DateObject = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat formatDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy");
String dateString = formatDate.format(DateObject);
System.out.println(dateString);
```

Now this gives me the current date in desired format. I want to find the Value of Date in same format exactly two months from this date.

I also tried to work with below approach :

```
LocalDate futureDate = LocalDate.now().plusMonths(2);
```

This gives me the date I want which is two months from now but in 2019-04-24 format. When I tried to format this date using SimpleDateFormat it is giving me Illegal Argument Exception.

Comment: Dates don't have any format. They're just data (i.e. a number of millis, or three integer fields for day, month and year). You choose how to format them when you transform them to a String using a date formatter. Stop using java.util.Date and SimpleDateFormat: they're obsolete. Read the javadoc of LocalDate to understand how to format it the way you want.

Comment: Thanks @JB. Will definitely go through it. Thanks alot for the info.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the **[`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)** class introduced in Java 8, avoid using the `SimpleDateFormat` :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     LocalDate futureDate = LocalDate.now().plusMonths(2);
     DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMMM yyyy");
     String dateStr = futureDate.format(formatter);
     System.out.println(dateStr);
}
```

Output:

```
24 April 2019
```

The `DateTimeFormatter` in Java 8 is immutable and thread-safe alternative to  `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: Thanks Amardeep ! This helped me resolve the problem.

Comment: @KovidMehta Glad to help!